# Qt: QPlastiqueStyle does not name a type

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning Qt from C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4. Chapter 19 refer to style sheet. The book is somehow old. it use Q QPlastique. Here is code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "candydialog.h"
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        QApplication::setStyle(new QPlastiqueStyle);

        QFile file(":/qss/candy.qss");
        file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
        app.setStyleSheet(file.readAll());

        CandyDialog dialog;
        dialog.show();

        return app.exec();
    }
```

I already knew that QPlastique is deprecated and replaced by fusion. but I have no Idea how to change above code.

Answer (score 2):

In Qt5 you should now use [QStyleFactory](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylefactory.html#details).

```
QStyle* QStyleFactory::create(const QString & key)
```

So in your case:

```
QStyle* fusion = QStyleFactory::create("fusion");
```

See [this blog post](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/10/30/cleaning-up-styles-in-qt5-and-adding-fusion/) for styles in Qt5.